Creating a summary of results table from {netmeta} without using RMarkdown - updated
I have spent hours trying to create a nice summary table that I can just copy and paste to a Word document but have failed. I am using the netmeta package to model a network meta-analysis. I have tried to use RMarkdown, stargazer, modelsummary, xtable, gt and just can't seem to do it and don't know where I'm going wrong.
When I try RMarkdown, I get the following error in the render window:
C:\Users\estua\AppData\Roaming\TinyTeX\texmf-dist\scripts\texlive\tlmgr.pl: Maybe the repository setting should be changed.
C:\Users\estua\AppData\Roaming\TinyTeX\texmf-dist\scripts\texlive\tlmgr.pl: More info: https://tug.org/texlive/acquire.html
! LaTeX Error: File `multirow.sty' not found.

! Emergency stop.
<read *> 

Error: LaTeX failed to compile RMarkdown.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See RMarkdown.log for more info.
Execution halted

I have tried to install the multirow.sty file using the parse_install function from {tinytex} but it just says that it fails to find a package that contains 'multirow.sty'.
When I create a dataframe to try and use the above packages (stargazer, modelsummary, xtable, gt), it seems to only output the raw data in a table, not these summary results below which is what I am looking for:
Number of pairwise comparisons: m = 32
Number of treatments: n = 7
Number of designs: d = 10

Random effects model

Treatment estimate (sm = 'MD', comparison: other treatments vs 'None'):
           MD            95%-CI    z p-value             95%-PI
ALA    1.8033 [-0.6348; 4.2414] 1.45  0.1472  [-3.8517; 7.4583]
DHAEPA 1.8189 [-2.7954; 6.4332] 0.77  0.4398  [-5.2774; 8.9152]
EA     1.3625 [-3.2319; 5.9569] 0.58  0.5611  [-5.7184; 8.4433]
LA     0.8687 [-1.6083; 3.3457] 0.69  0.4919  [-4.8065; 6.5439]
MUFA   0.4155 [-3.7984; 4.6293] 0.19  0.8468  [-6.3760; 7.2069]
None        .                 .    .       .                  .
SFA    1.4090 [-1.4802; 4.2982] 0.96  0.3392  [-4.4950; 7.3130]

Quantifying heterogeneity / inconsistency:
tau^2 = 5.4044; tau = 2.3247; I^2 = 85.7% [78.2%; 90.6%]

Tests of heterogeneity (within designs) and inconsistency (between designs):
                     Q d.f.  p-value
Total           104.62   15 < 0.0001
Within designs   13.80    4   0.0080
Between designs  90.82   11 < 0.0001

The output above is what you get when you type summary(df.netmeta).
Reproducible example below:
library('netmeta')
studlab <- c("Cardoso", "Baltazar", "Rossi", "Rossi", "Rossi", "Idrissi")
n.e <- c(6, 15, 8, 8, 7, 10)
mean.e <- c(25.52, 16.10, 23.44, 23.44, 23.44, 33.70)
sd.e <- c(2.68, 5.81, 3.6, 3.6, 3.98, 10.44)
n.c <- c(6, 15, 7, 7, 7, 12)
mean.c <- c(31.14, 16.8, 23.53, 19.18, 19.18, 32.9)
sd.c <- c(1.97, 5.03, 3.98, 5.11, 5.11, 9.7)
TE <- c(-5.62, -0.7, -0.09, 4.26, 4.35, 0.8)
seTE <- c(1.35, 1.98, 1.97, 2.31, 2.45, 4.32)
treat1 <- c("ALA", "LA", "LA", "LA", "ALA", "LA")
treat2 <- c("None", "None", "ALA", "None", "None", "ALA")
df <- data.frame(studlab, n.e, mean.e, sd.e, n.c, 
                 mean.c, sd.c, TE, seTE, treat1, treat2)
df.netmeta <- netmeta(TE = TE,
        seTE = seTE,
        treat1 = treat1,
        treat2 = treat2,
        studlab = studlab,
        data = df,
        sm = "MD",
        fixed = FALSE,
        random = TRUE,
        prediction = TRUE,
        reference.group = "None",
        details.chkmultiarm = TRUE,
        sep.trts = " vs ")
print(df.netmeta)


i would suggest the package docs or vignette. they have several built-in ways to summarize these objects altho i am not familiar with any of them: netleague(df.netmeta); nettable(df.netmeta); netgraph(df.netmeta); forest(df.netmeta) the first two can easily be put into a rectangular table. i personally only deal with html tables which can be opened in excel and copied to word

Could html tables be used in this instance? I cannot seem to find information on putting the summary results into a table in the package documents.

for example, htmlTable::htmlTable(nettable(df.netmeta, digits = 2)$common)
